# Show that the $\mathcal{F}^4(f)=f$ for all $f\in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform

I have some troubles with the following problem:

Consider the Schwartz space $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$, and view the Fourier transform as a linear map $\mathcal{F}:\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$.

Show that the $\mathcal{F}^4(f)=f$ for all $f\in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$

I have computed $\mathcal{F}^2(f)(x)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)e^{ix\xi} dm(x)=F^{*}(f)(\xi)$ which is  the inverse Fourier transform.
Now I am thinking I need to compute $F^{2}(F^{2}(f))$ but I don't know how to compute this so I get $f$.

Comment: Can you show $\mathcal{F}^2(f)=f\circ (-\mathrm{Id})$?

Comment: I don't know how to show that, but what would I use that for, and how would I show that?

Comment: That would prove the result easily: Apply $\mathcal{F}$ on both sides to get $\mathcal{F}^4(f)=\mathcal{F}(f\circ (-\mathrm{Id}))=f\circ (-\mathrm{Id})\circ (-\mathrm{Id)}=f$.